# How to restart Networking Stack in Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, service, virtualization

I am on a Windows 10 Pro laptop with several Virtualization platform on in: Hyper-V, VSL, VMWare, VirtualBox. Everytime I change Network Location like move to another Wifi Network, my virtual Networking Stacks stop working, so all services relies on interrupted: Virtual Networking DHCP Services, Network Routing DNS etc.

The simplest is solution is reboot Windows to reinitialize Virtual Networking Services. Sometimes I walk through all running services related to virtualization and get the services working. But this method seems not effectively.

Is there anyway to restart at once Host Networking Services that it relaunch all other services relied on it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Open PowerShell and run

```
netadapter
```

to see all your network interfaces and then restart your desired network as the example:

```
Restart-NetAdapter -Name Ethernet
```